# Is this element-of_{ij} - looking symbol the Levi-Civita symbol?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I'm reading this formula:

[image]

from [a page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hebb_rule)

Is the symbol that looks like an [element-of symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2208/index.htm) with two indices *i* and *j* the Levi-Civita symbol?

Mathematics is my weak-side so I'm not sure.

Actually I guessed on Levi-Civita not based on my expertise but by tried to look up the symbol from the [wikipedia table of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols). As it didn't help, so I thought I look up Einstein-notation and Kronecker delta although I knew it's not them... but the wikipedia footer lists Kronecker as "notable tensors" and by checking the whole list I've got Levi-Civita which seem to make sense in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line following the equation in your link to the page says

> The $\epsilon_{ij}$ is a constant known factor

Comment: ah, it eluded me. Thanks for pointing me out, I just skipped the sentence accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

The $\epsilon_{ij}$ is just a constant factor. The larger it is, the larger the change in synaptic strength during the learning session. Because the constant will be different for different synapses, there's a subscript $i$ and $j$.

It is not a Levi-Civita or any other standard function.

And by the way the name for that letter is "lunate [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon)".

Comment: thanks for telling me the name!